Fundamental physical concept behind inductance of a long wire above a ground plane

Please explain the underlying physics concept behind the inductance of a long wire above an infinite ideal ground plane. Sometimes the image method is used and sometimes the coupled magnetic flux method. Which one is physically correct and why?

Characteristic impedance of a wire over a ground plane

Is this approach correct? By using the image method there is flux between the upper wire and ground plane that is partly generated by the bottom wire. Is it not possible to calculate the partial inductance of the upper wire and ground plane and add them together? If you have an ideal ground plane then the return current through the plane will not generate a magnetic flux around the plane. So only the partial inductance of the upper wire is relevant. This inductance will be smaller than the inductance calculated with the image method.
